# How can I build bootimage without going through all Makefiles

Tags: makefile, linux-kernel, android-source

I am currently working on the Linux kernel for an Android phone. My workflow is:

1. Make changes to kernel code
2. Build with `make bootimage`
3. Flash with `fastboot flash boot`

This works fine. However building takes unnecessary long because `make bootimage` first goes through the entire tree and includes all `Android.mk` files. This takes longer than actually compiling the kernel and creating a boot image. Including these files should not be necessary since there are no changes to them. To decrease turnaround time in my workflow, I would like to speed up the build step.

When building other other projects, there are ways to to not build dependencies and thus skip reading all `Android.mk` files (for instance `mm`).

There is a make target `bootimage-nodeps` which seems to do the right thing: It makes a new boot image without going through all `Android.mk` files. Unfortunately dependencies also include the kernel itself (which therefore does not get built although there are changes).

My question is: Is there a way to build the kernel and create a boot image withouth having to read all `Android.mk` files.

Comment: This is a copy of the same question that I asked over at android.stackexchange.com where it was marked as off topic: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/173347/how-can-i-build-bootimage-without-going-through-all-makefiles. I hope to find an answer in this community.

Comment: You have to deeply understand build process of Android sources, thus you *have to* do a research of how Makefiles are written and what they call.

Comment: I just hope someone already knows.

Comment: Not sure if we can skip other Android.mk files but you can assign more jobs to make command, which can save your time. Eg. make bootimage -j32

Comment: Thanks. That's good advice. I already use `-j6` (my laptop has two hyperthreaded cores). I left this information out for clarity's sake. I doubt that increasing the number will help much with only four threads being able to run simultaneously. I will test how much I can gain.

Comment: bootimage is made of alot of projects, the environment need to find them all, and must go through all the Android.mk tree

Comment: But all dependencies are already built: The only missing piece is the kernel. The make target `bootimage-nodeps` takes care of assembling everything. On the other hand, building the kernel should be fairly self-contained, shouldn't it?

Comment: @justfortherec, but how build system, in particular `make`, will **know** that?

Comment: So, you mean I do `cd kernel/` and run `make` in there? Does that build for the right architecture and use the right configuration? It's such a simple idea that I have not tried it yet. Will do so.

Comment: @0andriy, running `make` in `kernel/` does not work. As expected, it is missing configuration.

Comment: @justfortherec if you are missing configuration - try to run "make help" in the kernel to see which configurations you can build.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case you 're still looking into it, try using the `showcommands` goal at `make`, for example :

```
make bootimage showcommands
```

The `showcommands` goals will show all commands needed to build the kernel and the bootimage. Some of the commands, including the one to create the bootimage have `$(hide)` in front and are not shown.

Once you know the commands and the arguments, next time you need to make the bootimage you can run the commands manually (without using `make bootimage` and without including all the makefiles).
I have exactly the same problem and this is the only working solution I've found.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can save time this way (since this solution needs to zip/unzip multiple times which needs more time then to search for all Android.mks on my machine) but since your question is:

> Is there a way to build the kernel and create a boot image withouth
>   having to read all Android.mk files.

you could give this a try:

Preperations:

1. call `make dist` once
2. unzip the `target_files.zip` in `out/dist/`

now create a script that does the following for you:

1. overwrite the kernel in your unpacked `target_files` with your newly build kernel
2. zip your `target_files` with your new kernel
3. use the python script `img_from_target_files` from `build/tools/releasetools/` with the extra parameter `-z`. Example: `img_from_target_files -z out/dist/target_files.zip new_imgs.zip`
4. inside the newly created `new_imgs.zip` you will find your new boot.img with your new kernel

Comment: This is an interesting idea. However, this skips the crucial step that I want a solution for: How can I create my "newly built kernel" without going through all make files?

Creating the bootimage from a kernel is not the issue: The make target `bootimage-nodeps` that I mention in my question does exactly that. But for that I need a kernel in the first place. I am looking for a way to build this kernel that does not involve including all `Android.mk` files.

Comment: @justfortherec better add more context to your question. Like your android version, rom version and the kernel you are using because with the kernels I know I was able to simply run make to build them.

Comment: So, you just `cd kernel/` and `make` there? I will try that.

Comment: I have tried, that does not work. @IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII, what do you mean with "simply run make"?

Comment: @justfortherec exactly in my case I have a Makefile to build the kernel alone. Without knowing which rom/kernel/etc you use we can just guess what will work for you.

Comment: I am using a build system from Codeaurora. For all intents and purposes this should be equivalent to AOSP with kernel in tree. The manifest is here: https://code.fairphone.com/gerrit/fp2-dev/manifest

Answer (score 0):

You can try the make `SINGLE_SHOT`command - if you know the path to your Andorid.mk:-

`m -j8 ONE_SHOT_MAKEFILE=build/target/board/Android.mk bootimage`

This worked for me pretty well in Android L/M/N releases

Comment: This does look interesting. Doe you know what the difference to using `mm`/`mmm` is?

Reading your answer makes me realize that I should just try to find out what makefile is relevant for the kernel and `mmm` that directory. Issues is: I do not know which makefile that would be.

Comment: No sorry I have no idea about `mmm` Not sure if just doing a `mm` on the module would force linking the newly built module with the kernel image - Unless you just want to push the module lib (`.so`/ `.o`) to the target